# Efficient Method for Flood Filling a Numpy Boolean Matrix: How to Replace All 'False' Values Enclosed by 'True'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

For a given image mask matrix of shape `H x W` containing only `True` and `False` values, I wish to convert all `False` values to `True` when they are entirely enclosed by `True` values.

e.g.

```
mask = np.array([
    [True,  True,  True,  True,  True ],
    [True,  False, True,  False, True ],
    [True,  True,  True,  False, True ],
    [True,  False, False, False, True ],
    [True,  True,  True,  True,  True ]
])
```

The result should be

```
np.array([
    [True,  True,  True,  True,  True ],
    [True,  True,  True,  True,  True ],
    [True,  True,  True,  True,  True ],
    [True,  True,  True,  True,  True ],
    [True,  True,  True,  True,  True ]
])
```

I'm seeking an efficient approach to accomplish this, perhaps through a robust image processing library, rather than crafting a custom Python helper function.

Comment: cast to uint8 so opencv will accept it, then use whatever opencv routines there are? depending on the data, you might need to use findContours. maybe you can get away with simple floodfill calls, if you know what to fill. -- your condition seems higher-level. if it were related to the direct 8-neighborhood, you'd only ever fill single pixels.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you. Could you give a minimal example? I'm not quite proficient in opencv.

Comment: I'm creating a bit of code right now. -- your example's result is all true. what would an input-output pair look like where the result isn't all true?

Comment: You can use scikit-image routine to fill holes... https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes.html#scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `cv.findContours`.

This finds white islands, with whatever black ponds in them, then fills the islands.

In your example case, it would return a single contour that covers the entire domain. In my case, it will find three contours: the concave blob at the top, the small one on the left, and the large one on the right. It will not bother finding the little circle contained in the big circle.

```
tmp = src.astype(np.uint8).copy()

(cnts, _) = cv.findContours(
    tmp, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv.drawContours(
    image=tmp,
    contours=cnts, contourIdx=-1,
    color=1, thickness=cv.FILLED)

tmp = tmp.astype(bool)
```

Input, Output:

[image: input] ... [image: output]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.